# Graphical bug with mention notifications in chat

Tags: bug, chat

I was typing in Root Access chat and was mentioned simultaneously, when I saw this happen. It looks like the shadow was rendered offset from the number bubble.

I'm using Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 Professional x64 fully updated.

[image]

Comment: Just checked, it's supported.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported

Comment: @Tim By "it's supported", I'm assuming you mean the browser is supported. Yes, thanks for checking that. :)